# Server Side Changes Android O Notification Channels

Tags: android, notifications, push, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to add Android O Notification Channels support for my app.

In order to support Android O Notification Channels, what are the server side code changes if any that needs to be made? I did not see any mention in the Android Developer Docs related to server side changes required to support Android O Notification Channels.

Answer (score 1):

> what are the server side code changes if any that needs to be made?

That is up to you. Notifications and notification channels in Android have nothing to do with a server. If *you* decide that *your* code that creates *your* notifications and *your* notification channels depends on data in *your* server, *you* need to determine what changes *your* server will need to supply *your* revised data.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have different kinds of notifications and I think it makes sense then for me to have the grouping/channels setup from the server too.